# C++ Error Code C2784 could not deduce template argument for

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I am very new to object oriented programming and C++. I have been working on a matrix class and squarematrix class and have been running into some problems that I can't seem to figure out. The error code I have been getting is:

```
C2784:
'matrix<T,m,k> operator *(matrix<T,m,n> &,matrix<T,n,k> &)': could not 
deduce template argument for 'matrix<T,m,n> &' from 
'std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>'
```

I am really unsure why, because I have had other parts of my code work. The error is reported in the line with "product.elements = product.elements * elements;"

```
//Source.cpp
#include"Squarematrix.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<double> a = { 1, 2,4,5,6};
    squarematrix<double,2> N;
    N.assign(a);
    cout << N << N.pow(2)<< endl;
    return(0);
}

//Matrix.h
#ifndef _Matrix_
#define _Matrix_
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
template<class T, int m, int n>
class matrix {
public:
    vector<vector<T>> elements;
    int nrow;
    int ncol;
    matrix();
    matrix(matrix<T, m, n>&);
 };
template<class T, int m, int n>
matrix<T, m, n>::matrix() {
    vector<T>temp(n, 0);
    elements.assign(m, temp);
    nrow = m;  //m=0
    ncol = n;  //n=0
}
template<class T, int m, int n>
matrix<T, m, n>::matrix(matrix<T, m, n>& a) {
    elements = a.elements;
    nrow = m;
    ncol = n;
}
template<class T, int m, int n, int k>
matrix<T, m, k> operator*(const matrix<T, m, n>& a, const matrix<T, n, k>& b) {
matrix<T, m, k> product;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < n; h++)
            product.elements[i][j] += a.elements[i][h] * b.elements[h][j];
    }
}
return product;
}

template<class T, int m, int n>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<T, m, n>& input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    o << input.elements[i][j] << " ";
    o << endl;
    }
    return o;
}
#endif _Matrix_

//Squarematrix.h
#ifndef _Squarematrix_
#define _Squarematrix_

#include "Matrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T, int n>
class squarematrix : public matrix<T, n, n> {
public:
    squarematrix();
    squarematrix(squarematrix<T, n>&);

    squarematrix<T, n> pow(int); //calculate A^k
}; 
template<class T, int n>
squarematrix<T, n>::squarematrix(){
    vector<T>temp(n, 0);
    elements.assign(n, temp);
    nrow = n;  //n=0
    ncol = n;  //n=0
}
template<class T, int n>
squarematrix<T, n>::squarematrix(squarematrix<T, n>& a){
    elements = a.elements;
    nrow = n;
    ncol = n;
}
template<class T, int n>
squarematrix<T, n> squarematrix<T, n>::pow(int k){
    squarematrix<T, n> product;
    product.elements = elements;
    for (int power = 2; power <= k; power++) {
    product.elements = product.elements * elements;  
    }
    return product;
}
#endif _Squarematrix_
```

Comment: `_Matrix_` introduces a truck load of UB since it's an underscore followed by a capital letter. **Don't** do this else the compiler might eat your cat.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However can you elaborate a little more. Why is this a problem? What is/are UB?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `nrow` and `ncol` - they're template parameters and known at compile time.

But that's not the problem - you're multiplying `std::vector` where you should be multiplying `squarematrix`:

```
template<class T, int n>
squarematrix<T, n> squarematrix<T, n>::pow(int k){
    squarematrix<T, n> product = unit_matrix<T, n>();
    for (int power = 1; power <= k; power++) {
        product = product * *this;
    }
    return product;
}
```

where I've used a fictitious function that creates a unit matrix.
Writing that function left as an exercise.

Comment: I originally created a copy constructor for the squarematrix class that I thought would bypass this problem. (I forgot to post it with the rest of my code before- my bad). It is in there now. Nonetheless I'm getting the same error. I guess what I don't understand now is: I used a copy constructor to define product, yet it is creating a vector. Why?

Comment: @Bnakey A copy constructor won't make any difference as `product.elements = product.elements * elements;` doesn't involve any `squarematrix`.

Answer (score 1):

this code `product.elements = product.elements * elements` expresses that you want use two `std::vector` to multiply, but you don't support the `operator *` operation with two parameters whose type is `std::vector`.
In your code, you support a `operator *` operation with type matrix, so if you want use it, you should change the code `product.elements = product.elements * elements` to `product.elements = (product * *this).elements`

that will be OK. 
so the code of the member function pow of class `Squarematrix` is:

```
template<class T, int n>
squarematrix<T, n> squarematrix<T, n>::pow(int k){
    squarematrix<T, n> product;
    product.elements = this->elements;
    for (int power = 2; power <= k; power++) {
        product.elements = (product * *this).elements;
    }       
    return product;
}
```

at last , `#endif` is the end of some predefined and don't follow some macro, otherwise, the compiler will throw some warnings or errors.